# Get detail info based on a different column's value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table that contains letter information.  This table keeps track of different types of letters that can be used to send to clients. Each letter has its own specific information letter fields.  This table contains letterID, LetterName, LetterNumber and LetterField.

```
CREATE TABLE #LETTERINFO(  
    LETTERID INT,
    LETTERNAME VARCHAR(MAX),
    LETTERNUMBER VARCHAR(MAX),
    LETTERFIELD VARCHAR(MAX)
)

INSERT INTO #LETTERINFO (LETTERID, LETTERNAME, LETTERNUMBER, LETTERFIELD) VALUES(101, 'ABC', 'SS_10001-20170101', 'FAXNUMBER')
INSERT INTO #LETTERINFO (LETTERID, LETTERNAME, LETTERNUMBER, LETTERFIELD) VALUES(101, 'ABC', 'SS_10001-20170101', 'PHONENUMBER')
INSERT INTO #LETTERINFO (LETTERID, LETTERNAME, LETTERNUMBER, LETTERFIELD) VALUES(101, 'ABC', 'SS_10001-20170101', 'STATE')
INSERT INTO #LETTERINFO (LETTERID, LETTERNAME, LETTERNUMBER, LETTERFIELD) VALUES(101, 'ABC', 'SS_10001-20170101', 'ZIP')
INSERT INTO #LETTERINFO (LETTERID, LETTERNAME, LETTERNUMBER, LETTERFIELD) VALUES(201, 'EFG', 'HF_10005-20170201', 'ACCOUNTNUMBER')
INSERT INTO #LETTERINFO (LETTERID, LETTERNAME, LETTERNUMBER, LETTERFIELD) VALUES(201, 'EFG', 'HF_10005-20170201', 'BKDATE')
INSERT INTO #LETTERINFO (LETTERID, LETTERNAME, LETTERNUMBER, LETTERFIELD) VALUES(201, 'EFG', 'HF_10005-20170201', 'ADDRESS1')
INSERT INTO #LETTERINFO (LETTERID, LETTERNAME, LETTERNUMBER, LETTERFIELD) VALUES(201, 'EFG', 'HF_10005-20170201', 'BKSTATE')
INSERT INTO #LETTERINFO (LETTERID, LETTERNAME, LETTERNUMBER, LETTERFIELD) VALUES(301, 'XYZ', 'HM_10001-20130109', 'VEMAIL')
INSERT INTO #LETTERINFO (LETTERID, LETTERNAME, LETTERNUMBER, LETTERFIELD) VALUES(301, 'XYZ', 'HM_10001-20130109', 'STATE')
INSERT INTO #LETTERINFO (LETTERID, LETTERNAME, LETTERNUMBER, LETTERFIELD) VALUES(301, 'XYZ', 'HM_10001-20130109', 'VTYPECODE')
INSERT INTO #LETTERINFO (LETTERID, LETTERNAME, LETTERNUMBER, LETTERFIELD) VALUES(301, 'XYZ', 'HM_10001-20130109', 'ADDRESS1')
INSERT INTO #LETTERINFO (LETTERID, LETTERNAME, LETTERNUMBER, LETTERFIELD) VALUES(301, 'XYZ', 'HM_10001-20130109', 'CUSTNAME')
```

There is a client table that contains client information including all the letter fields described above.
[client detail information table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2C4I.jpg)

What I am trying to do is I would like to select info from the Client table and only view information related to a specific letter.  So if I want to view information for only LetterNumber SS_10001-20170101 I want to see all the values from the client table related to that letter

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you want to just use a simple where clause

```
SELECT * FROM tblClient WHERE LETTERNUMBER = 'SS_10001-20170101'
```

Comment: I want the values for that letter from the detail table.  That letter consists of columns FAXNUMBER, PHONENUMBER, STATE, ZIP in the client table. I forgot to add the letterID in the Client table